# construct a new method printList which displays the contents of a LinkedList<String>

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, printing

how to print out this new data structure by constructing a new method printList which displays the contents of a LinkedList aList. **using (print) as a template.**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {    
    String[] anArray=null;
    if (event.getSource() == reading) {
        String s = txt1.getText();
        String delims = expression.getText(); 
        anArray = s.split(delims);
        result.setText("");
        print(anArray);
    } 
    LinkedList<String> mkList;
    java.util.List<String> aList = new LinkedList<String>();

} // actionPerformed

public LinkedList<String> mkList(String[] sa) {
    LinkedList<String> st = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sa.length && sa[i] != null; i++)
        st.add(sa[i] + "\n");
    return st;
} // mkList

public void print(String[] sa) {  
   for (int i = 0; i < sa.length && sa[i] != null; i++)
        result.append(sa[i] + "\n");
   // Log the results to the terminal
   System.out.println("Input: '" + txt1.getText() + "'");
   System.out.println("Regular Expression: '" + expression.getText() +"'");
   System.out.println("Output:\n" + result.getText());
} // print
```

Comment: `System.out.println(aList);`?

Comment: using (print) as a template.

Answer (score 2):

Simply `System.out.println(aList);`

OR

```
public void printList (LinkedList<String> aList) {
    for(String currentString : aList){
        System.out.println(currentString);
    }
}
```

Comment: using (print) as a template.

Comment: @user2145688 What is wrong with this answer? It iterates over the loop exactly like your `print` method...

Comment: sorry didn't understand it at the beginning its actually quite good, but how would u call it now in Action preform to actually make it print because it won't be any use like this

Comment: After your `print(anArray);` statement, call `printList(java.util.Arrays.asList(anArray));`

Comment: doesn't compile I have been having this problem from the beginning

Comment: printList(java.util.LinkedList<java.lang.String>); in ArrTokenTest cannot be applied to (java.util.List<java.lang.String>)

Comment: You already have a method called `makeList`. Use `printList` with `makeList` like this - `printList(makeList(anArray));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution as well:)

```
public void printList (LinkedList<String> aList) {
    System.out.println(aList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "\n"););
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All standards Java collections have a sensible `toString()` implementation. Usually the elements are enclosed between square brackets "[", and elements are comma separated. toString() is invoked on each elements. See [AbstractCollection source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#430)

If this representation fits your needs, then just use the `toString`. No need to write code.

If you want a custom representation then can use or write a helper method. The [Joiner class](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained) from Guava is really useful and should be part of the JDK. You can see it as a reducer in functional languages, you can also add a map step using `Iterators.transform()` if you want to apply a specific operation to each element.

Obviously it makes no sense to use Guava only for the Joiner class. You can also write you own method. Use AbstractCollection.toString() or Joiner.join() as a reference.